# Using SWIG with pointer to function in C struct

Tags: python, c, function, pointers, swig

I'm trying to write a SWIG wrapper for a C library that uses pointers to functions in its structs.  I can't figure out how to handle structs that contain function pointers.  A simplified example follows.

test.i:

```
/* test.i */

%module test
%{

typedef struct {
    int (*my_func)(int);
} test_struct;

int add1(int n) { return n+1; }

test_struct *init_test()
{
    test_struct *t = (test_struct*) malloc(sizeof(test_struct));
    t->my_func = add1;
}
%}

typedef struct {
    int (*my_func)(int);
} test_struct;

extern test_struct *init_test();
```

sample session:

```
Python 2.6.2 (release26-maint, Apr 19 2009, 01:56:41) 
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> t = test.init_test()
>>> t
<test.test_struct; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'test_struct *' at 0xa1cafd0> >
>>> t.my_func
<Swig Object of type 'int (*)(int)' at 0xb8009810>
>>> t.my_func(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'PySwigObject' object is not callable
```

Anyone know if it's possible to get **t.my_func(1)** to return 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer.  If I declare the function pointer as a SWIG "member function", it seems to work as expected:

```
%module test
%{

typedef struct {
  int (*my_func)(int);
} test_struct;

int add1(int n) { return n+1; }

test_struct *init_test()
{
    test_struct *t = (test_struct*) malloc(sizeof(test_struct));
    t->my_func = add1;
    return t;
}

%}

typedef struct {
    int my_func(int);
} test_struct;

extern test_struct *init_test();
```

Session:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.2 (release26-maint, Apr 19 2009, 01:56:41) 
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> t = test.init_test()
>>> t.my_func(1)
2
```

I was hoping for something that wouldn't require writing any custom SWIG-specific code (I'd prefer to just "%include" my headers without modification), but this will do I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to "return t;" in init_test():

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

typedef struct {
 int (*my_func)(int);
} test_struct;

int add1(int n) { return n+1; }

test_struct *init_test(){
  test_struct *t = (test_struct*) malloc(sizeof(test_struct));
  t->my_func = add1;
  return t;
}

int main(){
  test_struct *s=init_test();

  printf( "%i\n", s->my_func(1) );
}
```

Comment: You're right, thanks.  Sorry it was an error in transcribing my question from the test code I was using.

Answer (score 0):

There is a current work with already satisfacting result about to have C bindings from C++ code.

So the simplest way seems to

1. Create C++ code instead of C.
2. Clone this unmerged branch https://github.com/swig/swig/pull/2086 and to compile from source.
3. Create python bindings.

Then you could use the `-c` option in order to provide C bindings as well as python. Then your code will be avaible in C as well as in Python.